# Fuzzy match string with jq

Tags: json, select, jq, string-matching

Let's say I have some JSON in a file, it's a subset of JSON data extracted from a larger JSON file - that's why I'll use `stream` later in my attempted solution - and it looks like this:

```
[
{"_id":"1","@":{},"article":false,"body":"Hello world","comments":"3","createdAt":"20201007200628","creator":{"id":"4a7ba8fd719d43598b977dd548eed6aa","bio":"","blocked":false,"followed":false,"human":false,"integration":false,"joined":"20201007200628","muted":false,"name":"mkscott","rss":false,"private":false,"username":"mkscott","verified":false,"verifiedComments":false,"badges":[],"score":"0","interactions":258,"state":1},"depth":"0","depthRaw":0,"hashtags":[],"id":"2d4126e342ed46509b55facb49b992a5","impressions":"3","links":[],"sensitive":false,"state":4,"upvotes":"0"},
{"_id":"2","@":{},"article":false,"body":"Goodbye world","comments":"3","createdAt":"20201007200628","creator":{"id":"4a7ba8fd719d43598b977dd548eed6aa","bio":"","blocked":false,"followed":false,"human":false,"integration":false,"joined":"20201007200628","muted":false,"name":"mkscott","rss":false,"private":false,"username":"mkscott","verified":false,"verifiedComments":false,"badges":[],"score":"0","interactions":258,"state":1},"depth":"0","depthRaw":0,"hashtags":[],"id":"2d4126e342ed46509b55facb49b992a5","impressions":"3","links":[],"sensitive":false,"state":4,"upvotes":"0"}
],
[
{"_id":"55","@":{},"article":false,"body":"Hello world","comments":"3","createdAt":"20201007200628","creator":{"id":"3a7ba8fd719d43598b977dd548eed6aa","bio":"","blocked":false,"followed":false,"human":false,"integration":false,"joined":"20201007200628","muted":false,"name":"mkscott","rss":false,"private":false,"username":"jkscott","verified":false,"verifiedComments":false,"badges":[],"score":"0","interactions":258,"state":1},"depth":"0","depthRaw":0,"hashtags":[],"id":"2d4126e342ed46509b55facb49b992a5","impressions":"3","links":[],"sensitive":false,"state":4,"upvotes":"0"},
{"_id":"56","@":{},"article":false,"body":"Goodbye world","comments":"3","createdAt":"20201007200628","creator":{"id":"3a7ba8fd719d43598b977dd548eed6aa","bio":"","blocked":false,"followed":false,"human":false,"integration":false,"joined":"20201007200628","muted":false,"name":"mkscott","rss":false,"private":false,"username":"jkscott","verified":false,"verifiedComments":false,"badges":[],"score":"0","interactions":258,"state":1},"depth":"0","depthRaw":0,"hashtags":[],"id":"2d4126e342ed46509b55facb49b992a5","impressions":"3","links":[],"sensitive":false,"state":4,"upvotes":"0"}
]
```

It describes 4 posts written by 2 different authors, with unique `_id` fields for each post. Both authors wrote 2 posts, where 1 says "Hello World" and the other says "Goodbye World".

I want to match on the word "Hello" and return the `_id` only for fields containing "Hello". The expected result is:

```
1
55
```

The closest I could come in my attempt was:

```
jq -nr --stream '
fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs))
| select(.body %like% "Hello")
| ._id
' <input_file
```

Comment: The JSON shown is invalid.

Comment: @BenjaminW. It's a subset, not a complete JSON file that I'm dealing with

Comment: That makes it hard to experiment, though, as jq complains.

Comment: @BenjaminW. unfortunately, that is the real world scenario of what the data looks like. I am new to jq but I was told that if one uses `stream` jq can handle the truncated JSON. If you want to use some other sample JSON for testing purposes tho I'm sure this would work: http://www.json.org/example.html

Comment: @Hack-R - You indicate that your actual file is valid JSON.  It should therefore be quite straightforward to provide here a valid JSON snippet that is representative of the larger document.  That is what the guidelines at [mcve] envision.

Comment: @peak I disagree - the MRE requires a reproducible example of the actual problem I'm working on, not an irrelevant complete JSON file that is in no way involved in the problem. I have never touched the complete version of the JSON file; it's not involved in my process and is stored by a web-app server.

Comment: You state that the actual problem starts with valid JSON. So let’s go with that.

Comment: @peak I never stated anything like that! The sever does not give me anything except what you see in the question. You're not making any sense.

Comment: You wrote “it's a subset of JSON data extracted from a larger JSON file“. JSON all the way down. So are you now saying that neither your subset nor the larger file is actually JSON?

Comment: @peak It is a **subset** yes. Not a complete JSON file. I never said it was a complete JSON file. It is a *subset*.

Comment: Please try reading what you wrote. “Let's say I have some JSON in a file, it's a subset of JSON data extracted from a larger JSON file.”

Comment: Anyway, I've updated both answers to show how one can handle the extra commas. It would be nice for others if you would update your Q to clarify that the extract is comma-delimited JSON.  (I'm still curious to know what process is responsible for producing such a stream.)

Comment: @peak I'm afraid you're not reading it correctly. Think about what it says. "I have some JSON in a file, **it's a subset**" which means that what I have is a subset. This was further clarified in the question and in comments before your participation began.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the input is modified slightly to make it a stream of the arrays as shown in the Q:

```
jq -nr --stream '
  fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs))
  | select(.body | test("Hello"))
  | ._id
'
```

produces the desired output.

`test` uses regex matching.  In your case, it seems you could use simple substring matching instead.

### Handling extraneous commas

Assuming the input has commas between a stream of valid JSON exactly as shown, you could presumably use `sed` to remove them first.

Or, if you want an only-jq solution, use the following in conjunction with the -n, -r and --stream command-line options:

```
def iterate:
  fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs?))
  | select(.body | test("Hello"))
  | ._id,
    iterate;


iterate
```

(Notice the "?".)

Answer (score 0):

The streaming parser (invoked with --stream) is usually not needed for the kind of task you describe, so in this response, I'm going to assume that the following (or a variant thereof) will suffice:

```
.[]
| select( .body | test("Hello") )._id
```

This of course assumes that the input is valid JSON.

#### Handling comma-delimited JSON

If your input is a comma-delimited stream of JSON as shown in the Q, you could use the following in conjunction with the -n command-line option:

```
# This is a variant of the built-in `recurse/1`:
def iterate(f): def r: f | (., r); r;

iterate( inputs? | .[] | select( .body | test("Hello") )._id )
```

Please note that this assumes that whatever occurs on a line after a delimiting comma can be ignored.

Comment: Why would you assume that when I clearly specified that it's not the case?

Comment: You wrote: “Let's say I have some JSON in a file”, not: “Let's say I have some comma-separated JSON in a file.”